# How can I Fade Paint over time?

Tags: unity, fragment-shader, rendertexture

I want to fading my paint over time like this:

but currently It's gray! what Is the problem?

[image: Gray Problem]

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


// Collider & Renderer Required
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class Paint : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material PaintMat; 

    private Texture mainTexture; // The texture used in the original material
    private RenderTexture renderTexture; // Work render texture (drawn here)

    // shader's propertyID
    private int mainTexturePropertyID;
    private int paintUVPropertyID;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        // property id set
        mainTexturePropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("_MainTex");
        paintUVPropertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("_PaintUV");

        // Get the main texture set for the material
        mainTexture = PaintMat.GetTexture(mainTexturePropertyID);

        // create a renderTexture 
        renderTexture = new RenderTexture(mainTexture.width, mainTexture.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Default);

        // Copy main texture to render texture
        Graphics.Blit(mainTexture, renderTexture);

        // set the main texture for the material with the render texture
        PaintMat.SetTexture(mainTexturePropertyID, renderTexture);
    }

    // I hope this is necessary
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        renderTexture.Release(); // render texture open
        PaintMat.SetTexture(mainTexturePropertyID, mainTexture); // Return to the original texture
    }


    void Update()
    {

        // Acquire the uv of the touched place
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                // Put that
                PaintOnUV(hitInfo.textureCoord);
            }
        }else{
            PaintOnUV(new Vector2(1000,1000));//Just Update
        }
    }

    private void PaintOnUV(Vector2 uv)
    {
        // Create buffer 
        var renderTextureBuffer = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height);
        PaintMat.SetVector(paintUVPropertyID, uv);

        Graphics.Blit(renderTexture, renderTextureBuffer, PaintMat); //Copy the material rendered texture to buffer , You can not write directly
        Graphics.Blit(renderTextureBuffer, renderTexture); // Write back from buffer to render texture
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTextureBuffer); // Release buffer
    }
}
```

Shader:

```
   Shader "Hidden/Paint"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _PaintUV("Hit UV Position", VECTOR) = (0, 0, 0, 0) // Position to  painting with brush
        _FadeTime("FadeTime",Float) = 50
    }
    SubShader
    {
Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
ZWrite Off Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha Cull Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex,_Temp;
            float4 _PaintUV;
            float _FadeTime;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 temp = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                i.uv -= _PaintUV.xy;
                i.uv +=0.5;
                float paint = length(i.uv-0.5 );
                paint = step(paint,0.05);
                float mask = paint+temp;
                float percent = 1.0/500;//why Is gray? can't fade completely!
                percent = 1.0/1000;//not Fade!!
                mask-= percent;
                return  mask;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can download and test this from my [github](https://github.com/smkplus/FadeDisplacement).

Comment: What range of values does `_FadeTime` get?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 `float percent` range is between `0 - 1` so when `_FadeTime = 500` , `1/500.0 = 0.002`.I store the result In RenderTexture and return It again by reducing alpha of previous result,this cycle creates the fading effect over the time.

Comment: I don't think you should edit the question to ask something different after getting a solution to the original question. Another question should be asked instead.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 ok I will edit It to the previous time

Answer (score 2):

`frag` is declared as returning a Vector (`float4`). What you are actually returning is a Scalar (`float`). This results in a Scalar-to-Vector conversion which is defined as:

> **Scalar-to-Vector**
>
> Such conversions are always valid. This cast works by **copying** the scalar to **fill** the vector.

(Emphasis mine).

This means that when your code returns `0.02` what it's actually returning is `(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)`.

Or...gray.

Comment: thanks I could fix It.there Is only one problem => how can I set time to fading over time?

Comment: It's already "fading over time." You're going to need to clarify.

Comment: I need `Lerp(Paint,0,FadeTime)` Paint to fading.Length of time to fade.to clarify you can see [this shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xd3fDr) and change the `fadeTime 50` to `fadeTime 500` In `Buf A`.I just want to increase the trail length over time.

Comment: I need to change trail length like this [Gif 1](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16706911/39346539-eafa952a-4a03-11e8-945d-664db329675f.gif)

[Gif 2](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16706911/39346537-e6bdabe6-4a03-11e8-9fdc-d173eae5c675.gif).please help me

Comment: when I try to Increase trail length I have this problem [Gray Problem](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16706911/39363044-13aace2e-4a3e-11e8-8747-206b028c3180.gif)              `float result = lerp(mask,0,0.01);
    return result;`

Comment: `percent = 1.0/1000; mask-= percent;` <-- there's your fading math. Do whatever you want with it.